# Access Struts2 Action with JSTL

Tags: java, struts2, jstl

I'm migrating a Java Web Application using regular Servlets to Struts2 Actions.

I can't seem to be able to access the Action objects on the JSP using JSTL tags. The tags were working correctly before the migration, but now they just show the variable name. I can, however, access the object with Struts2 tags, so i'm not sure what the problem is with JSTL.

My Action has the following object:

```
private String prueba = "hola";

public String getPrueba() {
    return prueba;
}

public void setPrueba(String prueba) {
    this.prueba = prueba;
}
```

On the JPS:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
```

This tag shows "${prueba}" on the screen.

```
<c:out value="${prueba}" />
```

While this tag correctly shows "hola".

```
<s:property value="prueba"/>
```

I have the latest version of JSTL library on my classpath, and no errors are shown on the console, so I'm not sure what could be the problem. Do I need to configure something else, either on struts.xml, web.xml or my Action class?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

My struts.xml

```
<struts><!-- Configuration for the default package. -->

    <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">

        <action name="listaAutos" 
            class="com.neoris.training.lab.autos.negocios.AutomovilServlet"
            method="service">
            <result name="success">/listaautos.jsp</result>
        </action>

    </package>
</struts>
```

My web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
"http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

    <web-app>
      <display-name>Team1PrjStruts</display-name>
      <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
      </filter>

      <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      </filter-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

Comment: What version of struts2 do yo use?

Comment: I'm using Struts2 2.1.8.1, or at least that's the version of the core library.

Comment: Start changing `FilterDispatcher` (that is deprecated since 2.1.3) to `StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter`

Comment: Ok, thanks for that tip. Still, JSTL doesn't seem to work. :(

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Also can you make sure you have jstl-xx.jar in your class-path?

[Why can't I use JSTL-style EL expressions in Struts tags?](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.1.x/docs/why-cant-i-use-jstl-style-el-expressions-in-struts-tags.html)

> As of Struts version 2.0.9 the JSTL/JSP expression language (EL) has
>   been disabled for Struts tag attributes which evaluate OGNL. This is a
>   precaution against security vulnerabilities that can result from the
>   double-evaluation that occurs when an attribute is first processed as
>   a JSTL/JSP EL expression and then the result is processed as an OGNL
>   expression. The solution is to express all dynamic attribute values in
>   Struts tags using OGNL expressions directly.

http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/using-struts-and-xwork-with-jsp-20-and-jstl-11.html

**But you could try this:**

http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/using-struts-and-xwork-with-jsp-20-and-jstl-11.html

Comment: He doesn't want to use JSTL in Struts tags: he wants to read Struts (Action) parameters in JSTL tags.

Comment: @AndreaLigios - my second links explains that and the example following in that link.

Comment: I have jstl-1.2.jar on my class-path. I don't fully understand what that interceptor is supposed to do. Is it what I need to make JSTL work on newer version of Struts2? I've tried that code on my proyect but even by changing the imports (I had to use com.opensymphony.xwork2. instead of com.opensymphony.xwork.) I'm getting some classes not found errors, and even by replacing them by what I think should be the right one, I'm getting a class not found error on the WebWorkStatics class. I'll try to re-read those links to see if I can figure it out, but I'd appreciate further input on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try `<c:out value="${action.prueba}" />` or simply `${action.prueba}`

Answer (score 0):

According to the fact that all Struts2 requests are rewrapped in `StrutsRequestWrapper` (and the `getAttribute` method is overloaded there to use ValueStack to search for variables/attributes if not found using plain JSTL EL way) - using just `${prueba}` from within JSP shall work perfectly fine.